# How to make profile page for each user posting on the blog?

Tags: plugins

We have out company blog and few employees write on this blog, what I want is when anyone click on the UserName of the user who wrote the post it navigate to this user profile page which we will write there a brief about this user experiences.

For example in this blog post: http://encosia.com/jquery-asp-net-web-api-and-json-net-walk-into-a-bar/
If you clicked on the "By Dave Ward;" It will open this user profile page.

We need to do the same in our blog, is there a plugin I should install?

Comment: This functionality is available in WP natively, but might require some edits to your archive.php file.  Is encosia your site, or an example site you are referencing?

Comment: example, it is not mine

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for here are Author pages, see [this Codex article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates).

Here are a couple of other articles that explain the process:

http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-authors-page-template/

http://wpengineer.com/1958/wordpress-3-0-specific-author-templates/

Often you'll want to display all the posts by that author after the author description. To get that link use `<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>` :

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author_posts_link

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Author templates - using the template file author.php - are a standard WP feature but not always included in all themes. You can use the code shown in the codex page below to grab author info and display it in author.php. You can also add more fields to the User Profile page that can be outputted on author.php.

Try copying author.php from the WP default twentyeleven theme and changing the html to match your theme.

See http://codex.wordpress.org/Author_Templates and search for plugins that augment the author feature http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=author and see different tutorial results for http://www.google.com/search?q=author+pages+wordpress